# Оптимизация MySQL где много условий where

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Сайт доска объявлений недвижимости, много фильтров (15-20) по параметрам недвижимости.
Каждый фильтр это одно where условие в select, в итоге если выбрать 4-5 фильтров, получаем 4-5 условий в селекте. Есть текстовые поля, например улица, район. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно такое оптимизировать? Ставить индексы на все поля?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно посмотреть поглубже - как работают индексы. MySQL выбирает только **один** индекс - по которому будет идти выборка. Индекс является доп-колонкой в таблице - не страшно для чтения если индексов очень много. Правда запись будет помедленнее - но обычно терпимо.

Если во where у нас 5 условий на 5 полей - максимальный прирост мы получим при добавлении индекса на все 5 полей. В принципе если добавить индексы по наиболее частым выборкам - будет достаточно быстро на объёме до 10 мил. записей.

Если больше - нужно шардить(резать на кусочки) таблицу, или использовать NoSql решения - которые ищут очень быстро по любым полям(в том числе не по точному совпадению) на огромных объёмах. Например мы для аналогичной задачи - доска объявлений использовали Apache Solr , влвали базу объяв 10 мил, остались довольны.

Answer (score 1):

20к записей - это мизер, даже без индексов все будет на приемлемой скорости работать.

В идеале смотрите какие запросы будут чаще всего (из каких фильтров состоять), добавляете индексы по таким полям, которые дадут максимальное сокращение выборки.

> Например, если фильтр по улице из 20к записей выберет 10, то индексы по другим полям не нужны. Однако, если в фильтре улица не участвует, понадобится фильтр по другим полям/комбинациям полей.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант — да, можно (в смысле сделать столько индексов, что вся таблица будет ими покрыта). Но лучше поработать с планировщиком запросов, скорее всего какие-то фильтры будут более часто используемые плюс, оцените время на запрос-материализацию, скорее всего, селект не самый ресурсоемкий. Т.е. выборка по одной таблице со множеством условий - в принципе не самый тяжкий вариант, вот join-ы множества таблиц с подзапросами - вот это уже поле для оптимизации. А так, о каком числе записей идет речь?

Comment: Порядка 20 тысяч на одном сайте, всего 20 сайтов на одном хостинге, у каждого своя база MySQL